# Как запустить функцию matlab?

Tags: matlab

Есть функция, подскажите как ее запустить?

```
function mu=bellmf(x, params)
%bellmf – bell membership function;
%x – input vector;
%params(1) – concentration coefficient (>0);
%params(2) – coordinate of maximuma.
a=params(1);
b=params(2);
mu=1./(1+ ((x-b)/a).^2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В командной строке (*command window*) создаёшь переменную **x** и массив **params** размером 1х2.
Далее в командной строке вызываешь функцию **mu=bellmf(x, params)**.

Пример что должно получиться:

```
>> x = 1;
>> params = [1, 0];
>> mu=bellmf(x, params)

mu =

    0.5000
```

А вообще советую посмотреть examples в [matlab help.](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/function-basics.html)